# How can Optimize function in R code

Tags: r, optimization

Optimization problem:

```
    x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,8,4,5)
    y <- c(-2,-5,-3,1,5,3,-17,1)
    alpha0 <- 0.01
    Q <- function(alpha, x, y){

        n <- length(x)
        mu <- sum(x)
        xi <- sum(y)
        L1 <- (alpha-1)*xi-alpha*mu
              -n*log(gamma(alpha))+n*alpha*log(alpha)
        return(-L1)
    }

      Qaf <- nlm(Q, alpha0, x, y, hessian=T)
      Qaf <- nlminb(alpha0, Q, x=x, y=y, hessian=T)
      Qaf <- optim(alpha0, Q, x=x, y=y, hessian=T, method="CG")
      Qaf <- optim(alpha0, Q, x=x, y=y, hessian=T, method="BFGS")
      Qaf <- optim(alpha0, Q, x=x, y=y, hessian=T, method="SANN")
      Qaf <- optim(alpha0, Q, x=x, y=y, hessian=T)
```

Every optimization gives the different result of parameter and different number of warnings() of NaN. Can I solve this problem re-parametrize the parameter space? How can I re-parametrize the parameter space and solve this by using R code?

Comment: for starters why are you summing `xi` and `mu`?

Comment: Looks like your function is increasing on `[0,1]` (try plotting it) so if you are minimizing `Q`, any optimizer will try to reach `alpha = 0`, eventually reach it or go negative. Something wrong with your formulation?

Comment: Function is correct. Yes, any optimizer can reach alpha=0 or negative. For this I need to change the parameter space like (-inf, inf) or anything else?

Comment: I think the point is that all optimization/minimization algorithms will reach the same conclusion, i.e. that the minimum is a boundary value, not a point with slope (derivative) of zero.  The difference between one method and another is most likely due to machine precision errors and little else.

Comment: Range of alpha is (0, Inf). Can I optimize function for theta=log(alpha), then I find alpha=exp(theta)?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to do it with the following code :

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 4, 5)
y <- c(-2, -5,-3, 1, 5, 3, -17, 1)

Q <- function(alpha, x, y)
{
  n <- length(x)
  mu <- sum(x)
  xi <- sum(y)
  L1 <- (alpha - 1) * xi - alpha * mu - n * log(gamma(alpha)) + n * alpha * log(alpha)
  
  if(is.na(L1) | is.nan(L1) | is.infinite(L1))
  {
    return(10 ^ 30)
    
  }else
  {
    return(-L1)
  }
}

library(DEoptim)
obj_DEoptim <- DEoptim(fn = Q, lower = 0, upper = 10000, x = x, y = y)

obj_DEoptim$optim$bestmem
par1 
0.1499712

obj_DEoptim$optim$bestval
7.249054
```